# Distinguish between DataGridViewButtonColumn and DataGridViewTextColumn cell click event

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 4 column in datagridview control,in which 2nd column is the datagridviewtext column whereas 3rd & 4th column are datagridviewbutton column.
How to fire different event for datagridviewbutton click and different event for datagridviewtext column as it comes both in datagirdview cellcontent click.
or anyother way to find button or text click inside datagridview cell content click.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that, in `CellContentClick` event, is to check the cell type, like this:

```
if (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewButtonCell)
{
    // handle button cell click
}
else if (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxCell)
{
    // handle textbox cell click
}
```

And same for other cell types.